# MySQL - Show record pairs in one record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following data in one table:

```
Time, Type, Kilometers
12:00, 1, 0.1
12:30, 2, 0.2
14:00, 1, 0.4
15:00, 2, 1.0
16:00, 1, 1.2
16:30, 2, 1.5
16:45, 1, 2.0
```

This data is sorted chronologically using the DateTime field. I would like to show these record 'pairs' as 1 row, like so:

```
StartTime, Type1Km, Type2Km
12:00, 0.1, 0.2
14:00, 0.4, 1.0
16:00, 1.2, 1.5
16:45, 2.0, NULL
```

There are a couple of caveats: If there is no Type1 to start, then show NULL in the resulting tables' Type1Km field. Similarly, if there is no Type2 end, show NULL in records' Type2Km field.

How could i do this?

Comment: The tricky part is that you're joining a time with type 1 with the next time of type 2. If there are 2 type 1's "in a row", then the Type2Km should be null, right?

Comment: @MPelletier - correct (this is unlikely to occur, but would be beneficial if the solution takes this into account)

Comment: I would be much easier to tackle if this table had an auto-increment column to link X to X+1 for the differential test...  Is there one, and just not presented above?

Comment: Further to what @DRapp asked: Would that be reliable? Would the times be inserted sequentially?

Comment: @DRapp, there is, however it cannot be guaranteed (and will likely not be) that type2 = X+1

Comment: @Simon, I didn't care about the Type column, just that an auto-increment for ITs ID to be +1 to the next ID...

Comment: Without row ID, it would end up being some seriously strange correlated outer join query. I don't even know if that's supported. My approach would be to fetch the results and arrange them in code :P

Comment: @DRAPP - i understand what your asking, sorry i didnt explain better. Unfortunately the ID's in the table are not +1 from the previous ID. Looks like i may have to build a temp table for this one (or use code in my IDE :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL lacks a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so you'll have to `UNION` two sets together.

This will get you the cases where `Type1Km` exists, whether or not `Type2Km` does.

```
SELECT
    t1.`Time` as StartTime,
    t1.`Kilometers` as Type1Km,
    t2.`Kilometers` as Type2Km
FROM `times` t1
LEFT JOIN `times` t2 ON t2.`Type` = 2
                    AND t2.`Time` = (SELECT `Time` FROM `times`
                                     WHERE `Time` > t1.`Time`
                                     ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1)
WHERE t1.`Type` = 1
```

Now we need the cases where `Type1Km` does not exist.

```
SELECT
    t2.`Time` as StartTime,
    NULL as Type1Km,
    t2.`Kilometers` as Type2Km
FROM `times` t2
LEFT JOIN `times` t1 ON t1.`Time` = (SELECT `Time` FROM `times`
                                     WHERE `Time` < t2.`Time`
                                     ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE t2.`Type` = 2
  AND (t1.`Type` = 2 OR t1.`Type` IS NULL)
```

`UNION` those together, and you have the desired result:

```
(
SELECT
    t1.`Time` as StartTime,
    t1.`Kilometers` as Type1Km,
    t2.`Kilometers` as Type2Km
FROM `times` t1
LEFT JOIN `times` t2 ON t2.`Type` = 2
                    AND t2.`Time` = (SELECT `Time` FROM `times`
                                     WHERE `Time` > t1.`Time`
                                     ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1)
WHERE t1.`Type` = 1

) UNION ALL (

SELECT
    t2.`Time` as StartTime,
    NULL as Type1Km,
    t2.`Kilometers` as Type2Km
FROM `times` t2
LEFT JOIN `times` t1 ON t1.`Time` = (SELECT `Time` FROM `times`
                                     WHERE `Time` < t2.`Time`
                                     ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE t2.`Type` = 2
  AND (t1.`Type` = 2 OR t1.`Type` IS NULL)
)

ORDER BY `StartTime`
```

---

*Update*

In my previous query, I forgot to account for having a "type 2" record at the very beginning. Updated to account for that. Here's the results I get:

Data in `times` table:

```
+----------+------+------------+
| Time     | Type | Kilometers |
+----------+------+------------+
| 11:00:00 |    2 |        0.1 |
| 12:00:00 |    1 |        0.1 |
| 12:30:00 |    2 |        0.2 |
| 14:00:00 |    1 |        0.4 |
| 14:30:00 |    1 |        0.8 |
| 15:00:00 |    2 |        1.0 |
| 15:30:00 |    2 |        0.2 |
| 16:00:00 |    1 |        1.2 |
| 16:30:00 |    2 |        1.5 |
| 16:45:00 |    1 |        2.0 |
+----------+------+------------+
```

Results of query:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
| StartTime | Type1Km | Type2Km |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| 11:00:00  |    NULL |     0.1 |
| 12:00:00  |     0.1 |     0.2 |
| 14:00:00  |     0.4 |    NULL |
| 14:30:00  |     0.8 |     1.0 |
| 15:30:00  |    NULL |     0.2 |
| 16:00:00  |     1.2 |     1.5 |
| 16:45:00  |     2.0 |    NULL |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, change your table structure to have a type1km and a type2km, then either update when adding kms or just sum up when selecting.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
select 
max(Time), 
substring_index(group_concat(if(type=2,null,Kilometers) order by type),',',1),
substring_index(group_concat(if(type=1,null,Kilometers) order by type desc),',',1) 
from your_table 
group by date_format(Time, '%H');
```

*i assuming group by the hour, and also worth nothing your example results is not precise*

To better explain what this *funny* query does

```
group_concat(if(type=2,null,Kilometers) order by type
-- this is ensure the Kilometers must NOT from type=2

group_concat(if(type=1,null,Kilometers) order by type desc
-- this is ensure the Kilometers must NOT from type=1
```